# Why are some of the HTML nodes faded?

Tags: html, firebug

The code nested within the div of class dropdown-menu is faded.

```
<li class="drop down">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Sign In
  <strong class="caret"></strong>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom:0px;">
    <form method="post" action="post_login" accept-charset="UTF-8">
      <input id="login" type="text" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" size="30" name="user[login]">
      <input id="login" type="password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" size="30" name="user[password]">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign In" style="clear: left; wdith: 100%; height=32px font-size:13px" name="commit">
    </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: The CSS in one of your inputs is wrong: `wdith: 100%; height=32px`. It should be `width: 100%; height:32px`.

Comment: Thanks. That, of course, doesn't affect the faded node.

Comment: That's why I didn't make it an answer. Just pointing it out.

Comment: Yep, I just wanted to make it clear to others it wasn't a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's not visible in the page.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be visible? I don't see anything in the code above that would hide it.

Comment: @erenon - What am I missing? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kPTbs/. I'm not hungover today so that's not it.

Comment: @j08691: That's in the style sheet. Look at the class names, it's logical that the drop-down of a drop-down menu is initially hidden.

Comment: Select the faded HTML item in Firebug and look right into `Style` tab. There should be `display:none` somewhere there probably.